# Making sure Google Script is compatible with new google workspace

Tags: google-apps-script

I am launching a MVP developed on Google using google app script to 3 architecture agency. This MVP enables to send email automatically, store PDF into G Drive, create bloc into google calendar etc.. It's all custom made for google users.

I am about to create their google workspace and transfer their domain/email adress.

I have looked up on the internet and I could find my answer therefore here's my question.

Is a google adress/workspace sufficient to make google app script work ? or I need to transfer the domain and email host to Google ?

In another way : Will my MVP work even though the initial email adresse where not created on Google ?

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions on this site should be specific... meaning only one question per post. Please [edit] the question to narrow it's scope to a single question / issue.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your question is about if the fact of having purchased the domain with another domain registrar and have both the domain and email service hosted in another place would make any difference for your script, correct? If so could you provide more details on all the Google services that your script is using?